# Sum of 10 years of compound interest on new principle each year with increasing rate

Tags: exponential-function, geometric-series

I'm trying to calculate 10 years of compound interest on a principle. The difficulty lies in the fact that the principle needs to be added to the compounded interest *each year*, and *each year* the interest rate needs to increase by 5%.

The best way I can explain it is with a formula, which would go something like this:

```
A = (P * (1 + 0.05)) + (P * ((1 + 0.05) ^ 2) ...
```

And so on up until 10. I don't want to write it manually because it doesn't suit the case. How can I write an expression that will output only the result after 10 (or `x`) amount of years?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the general formula for $n$ years is
$A=P\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\prod_{l=1}^{k}(1+0.05l)$ and you ask for a result similar to $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Comment: I think that's right? And I'm also suspecting it'll be too complex to express in an Excel cell.